# Calculating eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm following a paper found here: (https://bearspace.baylor.edu/Vince_Cronin/www/PBO_ed/FindingEigenvectors.pdf)

It states that if you have two given eigen values $\lambda_{1}$ and $\lambda_{2}$ then you can calculate the the eigenvectors by:
$$
\frac{1}{ \sqrt{1^{2} + (\frac{\lambda_{1} - \alpha}{3}})^{2}}
$$

Where $\lambda_{1}$ is the largest eigenvalue. I've tried with the example, and, this makes sense, but using the following covariance matrix:

$$
C = \begin{pmatrix} 4.5 & 4.5 \\ 4.5 & 4.5 \end{pmatrix},
$$

where the Eignvalues are given as $\lambda_{1} = 9.0, \lambda_{2} = 0.0$

I do the following:

$$
\alpha = ((9.0 - 4.5)/3 \cdot (9.0 - 4.5)/3 + (1 \cdot 1),
$$

and then:

$$
\beta = (1 / sqrt(\alpha))
$$

The result I get is: $\lambda_{1} = 0.5547$ when in actual fact the eigenvectors for this matrix is given as: $\lambda_{1} = 0.707$

I can't understand where I'm going wrong and I am probably missing something stupid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $3$ is from his worked example matrix.

For your problem, you should change $3$ to $4.5$.

You get:

$$
\alpha = ((9.0 - 4.5)/34.5\cdot (9.0 - 4.5)/4.5 + (1 \cdot 1) = 2,
$$

and then:

$$
\beta = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt\alpha} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks! I knew that it would be a simple thing! Is this the correct way to calculate the eigen vectors?

Comment: @Amzoti Why do you always delete your reminder to upvote and accept a useful answer?